# Java Spring Boot - Ler arquivo dentro do .Jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, pentaho

Estou fazendo uma classe que irá ler uma ETL Pentaho Kettle (transformação),
Coloquei o arquivo que a classe irá ler na pasta Resources/KTR.

Porém quando tento rodar o código como uma aplicação java (java -jar),
recebo um erro dizendo que o arquivo não existe,

Porém ele está tentando ler o arquivo do disco local e não de dentro do meu .jar

Como faço para ele ler o arquivo que está dentro do .jar ?

Estou usando Spring Boot 2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT e Java 1.8

```
public class run_tranform {

 public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
     String file="src/main/resources/KTR/transformation.ktr";

        try {
            KettleEnvironment.init();
            //TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta(file.getPath());
            TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta(file);
            Trans trans = new Trans( metaData );
            trans.execute( null );
            trans.waitUntilFinished();
            if ( trans.getErrors() > 0 ) {
                System.out.print( "Error Executing transformation" );
            }
        } catch( KettleException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Neste diretório em _runtime_ realmente não terá este arquivo. Ele estará em _classes/KTR_. Talvez a melhor forma seja algo como isto: `Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(resourceName).toURI()).toString()`. Veja se esse `TransMeta` tem construtor por _input stream_, talvez seja melhor

Comment: Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755351/4319922)

Comment: @BrunoCésar tentei utilizar do modo como disse, ficou assim:         Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("KTR/transformation.ktr").toURI()).toString(); porém estou recendo erro de null pointer quando tento fazer isso.....na verdade eu nem preciso ler o arquivo, apenas pegar o path dele dentro do jar para o TransMeta ler....pelo que pesquisei o input stream ainda não funciona com o TransMeta

Comment: @diego como disse, recomendo a você olhar a doc deste `TransMeta` e ver se ele tem construtor por _input stream_. Por _path_ ele provavelmente precisa de um físico, não deve conseguir trabalhar com um de _classpath_.